# Topic Similarity in one model to csv Matrix

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv, gensim

I want to generate a Topic to Topic Matrix in order to find similar topic to generate internal clusters with the function `gensim.models.ldamodel.diff` from gensim LDA.
How can I save my generated data into a csv with topics over topics and the distances (in this case hellinger distance) in the cells?
This code is not working for me:

```
from gensim import models
import pandas

dateiname_model1 = "lda.model"
model1 =  models.LdaModel.load(dateiname_model1)

topic_over_topic = model1.diff(model1, annotation=True)

topic_over_topic_speicherpfad = "topic_over_topic_similarity.csv"
pandas.DataFrame(topic_over_topic).to_csv(topic_over_topic_speicherpfad, sep=';')
```

Comment: Could it be because `gensim.models.ldamodel.diff` returns a tuple of matrices and not just the topic-over-topic matrix?

Comment: That might be possible. But what can be the answer to that problem? I dont really know how to deal with that

Comment: Unpacking a tuple works like this: `a, b = some_tuple`. See [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) of the docs. In your case try `topic_over_topic, annotation = model1.diff(model1, annotation=True)`. If that doesn't work, a more detailed problem description could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the code `topic_over_topic, annotation = model1.diff(model1, annotation=True)`:

```
from gensim import models
import pandas

dateiname_model1 = "lda.model"
model1 =  models.LdaModel.load(dateiname_model1)

topic_over_topic, annotation = model1.diff(model1, annotation=True)

topic_over_topic_speicherpfad = "topic_over_topic_similarity.csv"
pandas.DataFrame(topic_over_topic).to_csv(topic_over_topic_speicherpfad, sep=';')
```